# .NET 6 dependency injection and DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I want to use dependency injection together with DBContext across several class libraries.

In program.cs I could have this line of code:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(o=>o.UseSqlServer("My Connection String"));
```

The implementation of MyDbContext is placed in a seperate class library called DBModel.

Now I can add MyDbContext to the constructor of any class in my project, and thanks to dependency injection it automatically available. But here is the problem I can't solve. Lets say I have another class library called BusinessLogic. In the library I have a classes that depends on MyDbContext, but as far as I can see, they do not automatically get MyDbContext although I have specified it in the constructor in the same way as in the project where I call services.AddDbContext...

How do I correctly uses dependency injection in this case?

Comment: You'll need to register your BusinessLogic class with the DI framework also and inject it in (for example) a constructor in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyDbContext` class should expose a public constructor with the `DbContextOptions` Parameter such as

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext :              DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you could use it through controller injection?

Does this help?

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/  and "MyDbContext" should be "ApplicationDbContext"